# Animating a slider when scrolling

Tags: css, angularjs, animation, scroll, jquery-waypoints

On my website I would like to animate my slider so that users see he can "play" with it.
I would like the slider to start its animation only when the user scrolled enough to see it.
I tried to implement Waypoint without success.

Is there a pure Angular way to make it?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Could always be useful to somebody :

I created a directive, which triggered at a certain amount of pixels from the top q function with an interval which loops to update the value of the slider so that the slider is animated when you start seeing it on the screen.

```
if (this.pageYOffset >= 1300 ) {
      var iteration = 0;
          var interval = setInterval(function(){
           iteration += 1;
            if(iteration === 10){
                 clearInterval(interval);
                  }
           scope.slider += 1;
           }, 10);
       }
```